# Theoretical perfomance difference between multiple get() and single getline() in fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Say I'm reading from a file.

```
ifstream f("file.txt");

while (f.good())
{
  char c = is.get();
}
```

VS

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
string line;
while(f.good())
{
  getline(f, line);
}
```

Does it theoretically make a difference given the file handle is left open throughout the entire file read?

Comment: Probably not, but the only way to find out is to try it with your particular hardware, OS, compiler, etc.

Comment: I don't believe this question has a "theoretical answer", because I'm not quite sure the approaches are comparable in the first place.  The first form is likely using buffered I/O.  The second form may allocate more memory, leave holes, etc based on how big your strings are in your file.  But you might be doing this anyway if you're working with lines.  You should simply pick the thing that's more natural to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

If your stream isn't cached, there might be a noticeable difference between the two versions. If for some reason you don't open a file but rather a memory stream that is extremely fast, the multiple calls to `get` might be slower. That, of course, also depends on how `getline` is implemented.

So there is a theoretical difference. Of course, to see if there's an *actual* difference, you should try it out. Chances are you don't notice any difference.

Comment: "If your stream isn't cached" <- *and*, you have a perverse implementation whose std::filebuf doesn't buffer.  I mention this because your "it depends" description itself could be misleading (discussing makes it sound more likely a concern than it may be).